# Set Overylay in multiple containers

Tags: html, css

I add an overlay to an image, so when the mouse is over it shows a square in the image. The problem is when I add a second image and I want the same effect. It shows the square in the same place as the first image:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkt438sx/2/)

```css
.programs_content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding-top: 4em;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

.rect-img-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.rect-img-container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.rect-img-container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.middle {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.rect-img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.frame {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
  height: 72%;
}
```

```html
<div class="programs_content">
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="/pdf/programs/smartamine_M.pdf" target="_blank">
      <img
        class="rect-img image"
        src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
        alt=""
      />
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Open</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <span class="caption">Test1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="/pdf/programs/smartamine_ML.pdf" target="_blank">
      <img
        class="rect-img image"
        src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
        alt=""
      />
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Open</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <span class="caption">Test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want each photo to have an overlay depending on the hover photo, if I hover photo 1 shows it photo 1, if I hover photo 2, shown it in photo 2. How can I solve this? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the `position: relative` added to your container. This way the boundary is set for the `position: absolute` positioning of the child button instead of the document as the boundary. And side note, you could accomplish the same effect with far less html/css but that's another topic.

```css
.programs_content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding-top: 4em;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

.rect-img-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative; /* <--- Establish boundary for absolute children */
}

.rect-img-container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.rect-img-container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.middle {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.rect-img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.frame {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
  height: 72%;
}
```

```html
<div class="programs_content">
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="/pdf/programs/smartamine_M.pdf" target="_blank">
      <img
        class="rect-img image"
        src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
        alt=""
      />
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Open</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <span class="caption">Test1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="/pdf/programs/smartamine_ML.pdf" target="_blank">
      <img
        class="rect-img image"
        src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
        alt=""
      />
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Open</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <span class="caption">Test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```